# AngularJS routing in codepen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ngroute, codepen

https://codepen.io/a_shokn/pen/yEJpww?editors=1010

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html'

    })

    .when('/second',{
         templateUrl:'second.html'

    })

});
```

Here is the Link to my Code Snippet , My Question is Were Must we keep our files (in my case main.html and second.html) when using routing in anjular js

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, codepen doesn't support adding multiple files. You may try moving your code to [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) instead. Alternatively, you can try to use inline templates in the HTML. For example, to have `main.html` resolved, you may write this snippet in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
// contents of main.html
</script>
```

This will make AngularJS resolve the template using this `script` tag. You can find a working demo of your code [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXJGoo?editors=1010).

Comment: Will it provide the same functionality